# Can I use nunjucks to reflect what page I've come from

Tags: node.js, express, nunjucks

I am using a node / express / nunjucks app and want to know if there is a way to change data on a page depending where the user has come from.

In my case, I have page A and page B, and page B allows users to go back to page A to edit details. However I want the ability to edit those details only to show if they've come from page B first; not if they just land on A straight (I can only have one version of page A).

So I'm thinking I can do this in two ways; by either creating a link from B to A with a specific URL paramter such as 'website.com/pagea-edit' and use nunjucks to check if '-edit' exists in the url.

Something like:

`{% if url === 'pagea-edit' %}
do this
{% endif %}`

Or I can check what page referred from B to A but I can't find how to make this a conditiona. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The previous page is accessable through [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) (or referer) on front-end and `var referer = req.headers.referrer || req.headers.referer;` on back-end (Express).

So you can pass it to `nunjucks`-render and make decision to render the block or not.